# Using Auto Layout to change Column layout of UIButtons

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a UIView where in portrait mode the UIView contains 2 columns of UIButtons evenly spaced in a list format. I would like to setup my code so that when in landscape mode the columns go from 2 to 3 to accommodate for the wider space. No I guess I could do this using a UICollection view but I was wondering if it was possible to simplify the build buy using Auto Layout.

Sorry don't have any code yet, wanted to get some advice before I begin coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But I would suggest you to use *UICollectionView* because it makes the Developer's life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can readily devise one set of constraints that configures the buttons in two columns, and another set of constraints that configures the buttons in three columns, and swap those sets of constraints to change the layout; indeed, if you do it correctly, the change will be animated. In fact, if this is on iPhone so that there's a change in size classes, you can configure the *nib* so that the constraints get swapped automatically on rotation. But you will still have to *have* a complete set of constraints, one way or another, for both situations.